# How to set horizontal or vertical custom padding to tailwind

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

How i set custom horizontal or vertical padding to tailwind.
Code like this

```js
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  content: [
    `components/**/*.{vue,js}`,
    `layouts/**/*.vue`,
    `pages/**/*.vue`,
    `composables/**/*.{js,ts}`,
    `plugins/**/*.{js,ts}`,
    `App.{js,ts,vue}`,
    `app.{js,ts,vue}`,
  ],
}
```

Comment: Did you checked this one? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#customizing-your-theme

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#customizing-your-theme

This should work pretty well.

`tailwind.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      padding: {
        'yolo-swag': '666px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it like ```px-yolo-swag```

Comment: @AlisherUsmonov fastest approach would be to try it directly.